# How to create Model class in efficient way instead of adding a set of strings, c#

Tags: c#

My application uses some configuration data(added below).

```
    {
  "Mobile:techUK" :"977455454545",
  "Mobile:saleUK" :"977455454545",
  "Mobile:supportUK":"977455454545",
  
 "Mobile:techCH" :"977455454545",
  "Mobile:saleCH" :"977455454545",
  "Mobile:supportCH":"977455454545",

"Mobile:techUS" :"977455454545",
  "Mobile:saleUS" :"977455454545",
  "Mobile:supporUS":"977455454545",


}
```

Each time I added the same kind of string for different countries. And the model size is getting bigger and not easy to handle.

```
 public class MobileConfig: IMobileConfig
    {
        public class Info
        {

        public string? techUK { get; set; }
        public string? saleUK { get; set; }
        public string? supportUK { get; set; }
        public string? techCH { get; set; }
        public string? saleCH { get; set; }
        public string? supportCH { get; set; }
        public string? techUS { get; set; }
        public string? saleUS { get; set; }
        public string? supporUS { get; set; }
     


}
```

Injected these data into class using the below configuration
Class for mobile configuration

> ```
> services. Configure<MobileConfig.Info>(_configuration.GetSection("Mobile"));
>             services.AddTransient<IMobileConfig, MobileConfig>(s =>
>                 new MobileConfig(s.GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<MobileConfig.Info>>()));
> ```

How to map the model If added two classes like countries and categories.

Comment: Would a `Dictionary<string,string>` work for you?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou how it works using Dictionary<string, string>,Any example?

Answer (score 4):

I can see a pattern emerging from your post. I think it would it be easier to have your json with an array of objects like

```
[
  {
    "Country": "UK",
    "Tech": 977455454545,
    "Sale": 977455454545,
    "Support": 977455454545
  },
  {
    "Country": "CH",
    "Tech": 977455454545,
    "Sale": 977455454545,
    "Support": 977455454545
  },
  {
    "Country": "US",
    "Tech": 977455454545,
    "Sale": 977455454545,
    "Support": 977455454545
  }
]
```

A class to host data like

```
class Mobile
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Tech { get; set; }
    public string Sale { get; set; }
    public string Support { get; set; }
}
```

And then just read all configuration in one go :

```
string configData = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
var myMobiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mobile>>(configData);
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. Extensible and Encaptulating.